# Determining subsets in sigma field

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, elementary-set-theory

I am given a sample space $= \{a, b, c, d, e\}$ and told that $\{\{a,b\}, \{b, d, e\}\}$ is a subset of the sigma field, which other subsets must the sigma field contain?

I know the empty set and sample space lies in the sigma field, but what is the best approach to determine the others?

Comment: Please look at my edit to the question.  The MathJax code was not properly formatted. $\qquad$

Comment: What is the definition of sigma-field that you know? Surely there must be _something_ else that is known. Just two axioms "$\Omega \in \mathcal F$" and "If $A \in  \mathcal F$, then $A^c  \in \mathcal F$ seem to be far too few.

Comment: It must be closed under what properties?  Differences, complements, intersections, and unions, yeah?  Try building a list of all possible intersections and unions and complementations using the two sets you are already given and using things you add to the list in the process.  For example, $\{a,b\}$ is in your algebra, so $\{a,b\}^c = \{c,d,e\}$ must also be in it...

Comment: As an aside, you are essentially being asked to find the [sigma-algebra generated by the family](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sigma-algebra#.CF.83-algebra_generated_by_an_arbitrary_family) $\{\{a,b\},\{b,d,e\}\}$

Answer (score 0):

A $\Sigma$ field must be closed under complements, countable unions, and (as a result) countable intersections.

We must have $\emptyset, \, ${$a,b,c,d,e$} $ \in \Sigma$.

$\{a,b\}^c = \{c,d,e\}$, so $\{c,d,e\} \in \Sigma$ and $\{b,d,e\}^c = \{a,c\}$, so $\{a,c\} \in \Sigma$.

Hence $\{a\} = \{a,b\} \cap \{a,c\} \in \Sigma$, so $\{a\}^c \cap \{a,b\}$ = {b}, $\{a^c\} \cap \{a,c\} = \{c\} \in \Sigma$ and $\{a\}^c, \{b\}^c, \{c\}^c \in \Sigma$.

We can continue taking unions, intersections, and complements of elements of $\Sigma$ until $\Sigma$ is closed under each operation.